# Why should I make a separate partition for /tmp?

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, tmpfs

**Why should I make separate [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) for [`/tmp`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/tmp.html), [`/var`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/var.html) and [so on](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s2-diskpartrecommend-x86.html)?**

I can see more drawbacks than benefits. One benefit is that I can use [`ext4`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) with [journaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system) for [`/home`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/home.html) and [`ext4`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) without journaling for other partitions.

Main drawback is size limit. When I was partitioning my disk I was [taught](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s2-diskpartrecommend-x86.html) to allocate *at least 50MB* for `/tmp`, so I set 1GB `/tmp` partition. Now I have trouble because it's *definitely not enough*! Copying DVDs needs more free space. Even [caching](https://superuser.com/questions/235535/in-google-chrome-on-linux-where-is-the-flv-if-not-in-tmp) single [YouTube's concert](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLLCrWLjZOU) needs more than 1GB of free space on `/tmp` partition.

What are the benefits of having a separate `/tmp` partition?

Comment: if you have separate partitions for `home`, `var`, `tmp`, `...` then you don't need too much space for `/`. Good thing if someday you need to restore system/settings from backup image. There is countless reasons why it is good to keep different parts of system on differens partitions.

Comment: Nowadays Debian uses tmpfs for /tmp, it can autoresize to accommodate files and can move stuff to the swap if needed.

Comment: See also a [question on separate partitions generally](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/685/176171) and questions specific to [/boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256/176171) and [/var](https://askubuntu.com/q/56869/396228)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One common reason for making it a separate partition is to be able to mount it as `nosuid` and `noexec`. This prevents both privilege-escalation and arbitrary script execution from /tmp, respectively. This is particularly useful in multi-user environments (e.g. hosting) where unprivileged users will have access to read/write data to /tmp but should not be able to perform either of these actions.

Another justification would be to limit the amount of temporary data stored (since not everything cleans up after itself) to prevent other more important partitions from filling and causing service interruption and/or data loss.

Comment: But still estimating size of **/tmp** is difficult. 2 years ago I assumed 1GB is enough and now I can see I need more space for **/tmp**. It's difficult to judge what is more important safety reasons or inability to work with programs that need more than fixed **/tmp** size...

Comment: Use LVMs and leave some free space in your volume group. Allocate it to individual logical volumes (e.g. /tmp) as needed. LVM supports online resizing as do ext3/4.

Answer (score 8):

It also makes sense from the security standpoint. Since many programs write temporaries in `/tmp` and `/tmp` is automatically cleared (using insecure file deletion), this means a lot of *deleted but recoverable* files still reside on the `/tmp` partition. If you isolate this partition and make it smaller, then it's easier to securely clean it, e.g. using `sfill` from [the `secure-delete` package](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/sfill.1.html).

Answer (score 7):

Also when tmp is on separate partition:

- You can share tmp between couple of linux distributions on multi boot environment and save disk space
- tmp can be excluded from RAID setup (RAID disk space is at premium)
- tmp can reside on faster media than root (i.e. RAM disk, SSD disk)
- tmp can reside on media less prone to wearing (i.e root on Flash disk, tmp on regular disk or RAM disk)
- tmp can reside on separate disk drive (to spread workload)
- tmp can be mounted on different partition/disk if needs to be bigger without affecting the rest of the system simple by editing a line in /etc/fstab